# laravel and phantomjs cookie

Tags: laravel-4, phantomjs

I am trying to pass laravel cookie when executing phantomjs, but cant get it working.

```
//This is what I do on phantom JS script
phantom.addCookie({
    'name': 'laravel_session',
    'value': laravel_cookie,
    'domain': domain,
    'path': '/'
});
```

But what should the laravel_cookie be?

I tried various options emulating what the browser should hold to be recognized as logged in user:

```
Session::getId()
Crypt::encrypt(Session::getId())
```

None of which work, any ideas?

Comment: Why not just log in with phantomjs?